# The report belongs to a package that is not installed

Tags: bug-reporting, apport, installed-programs, signal

I have gotten the error message "The report belongs to a package that is not installed."

Generally I would just ignore that since seemingly there is no problem except I got a crash report and then I said to report the problem and then I get this.

Now, how can a package or program crash that is not even installed? Sounds a little paradox, isn't it?

What should I do with this?  Why does this even come up?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `apport` fails to see the parent package of the failed executable file. `apport`, which is Ubuntu's problem reporter, watches every problem in Program execution.

When a program crashes, `apport` is triggered to find the program *(It watches for the programs execution constantly, unless you disabled it)* which indicates **Abnormal program termination**. It finds the executable file which has crashed and search for the system for package that includes this executable file. When It fails to find a parent package containing that executable file, *(in dpkg's database)* It shows that error, saying "The report belongs to a package that is not installed."

#### For example:

I uses a program for my Wimax modem, called `wimaxc` *(which is not installed by any package manager)*. It sometimes fails and `apport` also fails to find the parent package of the executable file, `/usr/bin/wimaxc`, hence , It shows that error message.

#### To find the parent package of an executable file:

If you want to find the parent package of an executable file, for example `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` type the command below in a terminal:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

It will give you an output similar to this

```
gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

Here, `gnome-terminal` is the parent package of the file `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`.

**Note:** Whenever you installed a package, it is listed in the dpkg's database. So, if you use a program, not installed by the package manager *(such as apt-get, synaptic, aptitude or Software-Center)*, `apport` will always fail to find the parent package, when it crashes, because their is no parent package

Comment: It's not actually the *return value* ("*exit value*") that Apport watches for. A program *terminating and indicating failure* doesn't trigger Apport. (If you run `ls blah` and there's no file called `blah` in the current directory, `ls` *exits signalling failure*.) Apport is triggered when a program *crashes*, that is, when it *terminates abnormally*. Most of the time a program terminates signalling failure, it is still normal program termination and Apport is not triggered.

Comment: @EliahKagan, Sorry I mentioned the "exit value". Also not understand this "Most of the time a program terminates signalling failure, it is still normal program termination and Apport is not triggered".

Comment: You're confusing [crashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_(computing)#Application_crashes) (which triggers Apport) with [exit statues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) indicating failure (which does not trigger Apport). Exit statuses indicating failure are a normal part of everyday program functioning and don't even necessarily mean *anything* has gone wrong. Crashes (like [SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) and [SIGABRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABRT)) always mean something went wrong (except when produced intentionally to test crash handling facilities).

Answer (score 2):

The question that led me here was, "Which package isn't installed?"

I found the answer by sorting the contents of `/var/crash/` by date.